# Multiple Plot Matlab including image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I use the `tiledlayout(2,2)` command to create a plot in Matlab. The first three title fields filled with normal plots. The fourth and last field is a field with an image. I used the commands `IMG = 'mypic.tif'`and `imshow(IMG)`.I wonder why I can not change the size of my image. Is this not possible with the `tiledlayout`command? I have looked up the documentary for `tiledlayout` and `imshow()`, but found nothing which helps me.

Comment: Have you tried the `InnerPosition` [property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.layout.tiledchartlayout-properties.html)?

Comment: I tried it today, but it makes the three plots and the image bigger or smaller. I just want to make the image bigger and the plots shut stay at the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It indeed seems as if this is not possible using the `tiledlayout` functionality. However, it is possible using the `subplot` functionality. Below, I will give an example how this works.

Consider the following script:

```
% Generate some dummy data for the four plots
x = linspace(0, 2*pi, 25);
y = sin(x);

% Load sample image
image = imread('ngc6543a.jpg');

% Generate the figure
fig = figure(1);

% The three subplots
for i = 1:3
    subplot(2,2,i);
    plot(x, y);
end

% The image
subplot(2,2,4);
imshow(image);

% Increase size of the image
size_factor = 1.4; % 1.0 is original size

im_ax = fig.Children(1);    % axes belonging to image
dims = im_ax.Position(3:4); % current dimensions

dims_new = size_factor * dims;  % scale old dimensions
dxdy = (dims_new - dims) / 2;   % offset for left bottom corner of image

im_ax.Position = [im_ax.Position(1:2) - dxdy, dims_new]; % update position
```

In this script, we start by generating some dummy data for the three 'normal' plots and loading a sample image (this image came with my `MATLAB` installation). Subsequently, we create a figure. After the figure has been created, I add the three dummy plots to the figure using a `for` loop and the `subplot` functionality. Then, we plot the image using `imshow` in the fourth subplot.

Now, the interesting part begins. First of all, I define a scale factor for the image (`size_factor`). Then, I retrieve the axes in which the image is plotted and store it in `im_ax`. From this axes, I retrieve the last two elements of the `Position` field and store them in `dims`. These two elements define the size of the axes. Based on the value of `size_factor`, I calculate the new size of the axes and store this in `dims_new`. To ensure that the axes (and thus the image) remains centered, we need to calculate by how much we need to shift the left bottom corner of the axes (whose coordinates are stored in the first two elements of the `Position` field). This result is stored in `dxdy`. The last thing we do is simply updating the `Position` field of the axes in which the image is plotted.

Now, to show you some results:

1. `size_factor` equals `1.0`: [image: size_factor equals 1]
2. `size_factor` equals `1.4`: [image: size_factor equals 1.4]
3. `size_factor` equals `0.55`: [image: size_factor equals 0.55]